# Spring dependency injection controll

Tags: java, spring

How do I control/restrict the instantiation of bean?

Lets say, I have 2 beans

1. A.java
2. B.java

Scopes of the both the bean as singleton & configured inside Spring application context

If A bean gets instantiated then B shouldn't vice-versa if B gets instantiated the A shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) or [@Profile](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html).
For first annotation you can write a class which will check if your bean exists.